# What are the types of devices that should use analog ground?

Tags: microcontroller, current, grounding, ground-loop, emi-filtering

As the title says, what are the components that require a separation from the digital ground?

For example, currently, I have a PCB where the microcontroller is powered and grounded to analog ground and this has no effect on the performance of the analog components.

Could someone example what are the effects, some use cases and how to avoid ground loops?

Comment: This type of question appears regularly and there are numerous answers. One of these (happens to be mine but there are numerous others) is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185306/analog-power-ground-planes-doubts/185320#185320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Logic and power ground currents shared with low current analog ground will induce ground shift noise to high gain circuits.  Its just an application of Ohm’s Law for conduction noise injection of AC and DC differences.